# the data is not rendering in another grid. why?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, grid, row

i am trying to click on a row in one grid, and display its data in another grid. the column is named as content whose data i am trying to display. but when i click, i see the data in console.log but not in another grid. why? here is my code

any help would be highly appreciated

```
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    const rowIndex = event.currentTarget.rowIndex;
    const clickedContent = pimerror[rowIndex].content;
    setClickedContent(clickedContent);
    console.log(clickedContent);
  };


  <Grid item xs={12} lg={3.7}>
          <AdvancedTableView
            title="Test Files"
            id_sort="datetime"
            data={pimerror.map((error) => {
              
              return {
                ...error,
                datetime: moment(error.datetime, "YYYYMMDDHHmmss").format(
                  " DD/MM/YYYY, HH:mm:ss"
                ),
              };
            })}
          
            filter_list={["content"]}
           
            onRowClick={handleClick}
          />
        </Grid>



 <Grid item xs={12} lg={4}>
          <AdvancedTableView
            title="Clicked Content"
            data={{ content: clickedContent }} // pass clickedContent to data prop
            filter_list={[]}
          />
        </Grid>
```

Comment: please show full code of your component

Answer (score 0):

`useState` hook is actually asynchronous. That's why when you call `setClickedContent`, result will occur after some time.

In your case you can store clicked index with hook `useState`. And `clickedContent` can be calculated with hook `useMemo` when clicked index is changing.

You can look at the simple example I've created. Second table is rerendering after first is clicked.

```
export const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
export const arr2 = [
  { index: 1, value: "value1" },
  { index: 1, value: "value11" },
  { index: 1, value: "value111" },
  { index: 2, value: "value2" },
  { index: 2, value: "value22" },
  { index: 2, value: "value222" },
  { index: 3, value: "value3" },
  { index: 4, value: "value4" },
  { index: 5, value: "value5" }
];

export default function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<number>();

  const data = useMemo(() => arr2.filter((c) => c.index === selected), [
    selected
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>First</h1>
      <table>
        {arr1.map((item, i) => (
          <tr>
            <td role="button">
              <span onClick={() => setSelected(item)}>{item}</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </table>
      <h2>Second</h2>
      <table>
        {data.map((item, i) => (
          <tr>
            <td>{item.index}</td>
            <td>{item.value}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </table>
    </>
  );
}
```

Working example is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-usememo-y5tk58